# How to delete last page in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have document that contains two pages. At first I have table from top to bottom of page. Second page consists of single unprintable paragraph character. I cannot delete that character. I want to have only one page with table. Is is possible? I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> at last table cell, but it does not work. Software version: *5.0.0.5*

Comment: Try making the bottom margin smaller to see if the last character gets pulled to the first page.

Comment: Select the paragraph market symbol and make in the minimum font size (6 IIRC).

Comment: If the table fills a whole page, you can often shrink it imperceptibly to leave room for the following paragraph mark.  Look at the extra before/after spacing on each paragraph.  You can usually shrink that by 0.5 or 1 pt and it will accumulate over the whole table.  Look for opportunities to save a whole line within the table.  If one column has an extra line, you may be able to eliminate it by hyphenating a word, adjusting column widths, or fine-tuning spacing or word choice within the paragraph.  If there are lots of rows, you might gain space by using thinner horizontal lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables require a following paragraph.  To make it fit on one page, change the paragraph's font to size 2.  Also resize the table or bottom margin if necessary.

Alternatively, `Table -> Convert -> Table to Text` makes it so that no extra paragraph is required.

See https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/7412/how-i-can-delete-empty-line-after-table-in-writer/.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that was working for me:

- place the cursor at the end of the last cell
- press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>
  This will create a new line directly after the table
- delete the empty page